# How can I make two running emacs processes to exchange text like in one?

Tags: process

When I have a running emacs process, before running another, I can make the running one a server, and then running the next as a client.

When I have two emacs processes already running, how can I exchange text between buffers in them as if in one emacs process?

What is some good practice to avoid such hassle?

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at emacs server http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html. Somewhere there is a function to convert your instance to a server.

Comment: What about converting another instance to a client?

Comment: What do you try to do? A single Emacs can open frames on different monitors, however, only one can be active. Another way is to simply enable `global-auto-revert-mode`, that way whenever you same the buffer in one Emacs it will be reloaded in the other. Also, have you considered using a version control system like git or svn? Of course, updating isn't instantaneous (as it requires one user to commit any change), but it allows both users to work independent of each other and still contribute to the same source code.

Comment: I open emacs in two different terminal tabs. I want to copy and paste text between them, just like in one emacs process. @Lindydancer

Comment: Do you run the two Emacs processes on the same machine? If so, you can start one Emacs in deamon mode and attach to it from both terminal tabs. @Tim

Comment: They are already run as regular emacs processes.